# What is the significance of `:` sign in JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In javascript what does `:` mean except ternary condition.
Like if we write

```
$:1          returns 1
undefined:1  returns 1
a:1          returns 1
```

but

```
1:1         returns error
```

can someone please explain the scenario.

Comment: it's a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. got you.

Comment: the last one is not a valid label. it has the same rules, like for variable names.

Comment: got you @NinaScholz. Thanks. But why did you marked it as duplicate? The context of the two questions is completely different. Please don't discourage people from asking a question by marking duplicate. Anyway thanks for quick response